# Displaying multiple routes on a google map

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to display multiple routes on same map but am unable to do so.

No matter what I do I get only one route.

```
function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem.  [This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/ubomY2IT728) on a Google group for Google maps shows how to do it.

The author (a Google employee), wrote this:

> You should be able to create two DirectionsRenderer objects, each that
>   use the same map and different DirectionsResults.
>
> ```
> var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
> function renderDirections(result) {
>   var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
>   directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
>   directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
> }
>
> var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
> function requestDirections(start, end) {
>   directionsService.route({
>     origin: start,
>     destination: end,
>     travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
>   }, function(result) {
>     renderDirections(result);
>   });
> }
> requestDirections('Huntsville, AL', 'Boston, MA');
> requestDirections('Bakersfield, CA', 'Vancouver, BC');
> ```

I tried it and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try as follows?
Here I have captured one path and displayed it. You can do the same by writing `pointsArray = result.routes[1].overview_path;` besides it and display it in a new loop.

```
directionsService.route (request, function (result, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections (result);
                pointsArray = result.routes[0].overview_path;

                var i = 0;
                var j = 0;

                for (j = 0; j < pointsArray.length; j++)
                {
                    var point1 = new google.maps.Marker ({
                                                    position:pointsArray [j],
                                                    draggable:false,
                                                    map:map,
                                                    flat:true
                                                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: yes doing this result.routes[1].overview_path; is not giving me the second route.

Comment: @AJ. Maybe there is NO second route in this case? Have you tried all this with some different sets of coordinates too? Anyway, can you present your actual code here (containing result.routes[1].overview_path) for others to test?

Comment: Thanks Anisha. Yes there are 3 routes available. I will paste my code snippet here.