# google map api remove straight lines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing a MVC app using google map API.
There are 4 or more coordinates in my program. According to that I need to draw road path. This is my code so far.

```
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>

@section scripts
{
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBZxYACsC1qz9gticRd4mbki9Tes9qexdw&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var markers = [
            {
                "title": 'Canberra',
                "lat": '-35.2809',
                "lng": '149.1300',
                "description": ''

            },
             {
                 "title": 'Sydny',
                 "lat": '-33.8688',
                 "lng": '151.2093',
                 "description": ''

             },
              {
                  "title": 'Tamworth',
                  "lat": '-31.0927',
                  "lng": '150.9320',
                  "description": ''

              }
              ,
              {
                  "title": 'Brisbane',
                  "lat": '-27.465895',
                  "lng": '153.019519',
                  "description": ''

              }


    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        console.log('len ' + result.routes[0].overview_path.length)
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>


    }
```

The problem is the map is shown straight lines as well.
[image]

I need to remove straight lines from the map (should keep lines draw on road path) and what's wrong in my code? In addition, Markers should show only for starting point and destination point. But all points are shown as markers. So how to do it...? Please give me a direction for doing it....

Comment: [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t0fdy8bq/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behaviour drawing a route between two points in Google Maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23176212/inconsistent-behaviour-drawing-a-route-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your script you're drawing markers on the map. To avoid that comment out the line `map: map,`

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      // map: map,
      title: data.title
    });
```

To remove the straight lines from the map:

comment out the line

```
//poly.setPath(path);
```

You need to use a `DirectionsRenderer` to show routes on the map once the routes are returned by the `directionsService`.

Define a function to render the computed routes

```
function renderDirections(result) {
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
};
```

Add the rendering to the callback function of the directionsService

```
directionsService.route({
        origin: src,
        destination: des,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      }, function(result, status) {
        // if route is computed successfully, render it on map
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          console.log('len ' + result.routes[0].overview_path.length);
          renderDirections(result);
        } else {
          console.log("Error: ", status);
        }
      });
```

The issue here is that you're trying to display multiple routes on your map, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9043160/2314737) for details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Half of my work is done. Now straight line issue is ok. But still markers are shown. So how to fix it?